# Oracle query - how to make count to return values with 0

Tags: sql, oracle, count

How can I make a count to return also the values with 0 in it.

Example:

```
select count(1), equipment_name 
from   alarms.new_alarms 
where  equipment_name in (
           select eqp from ne_db.ne_list)
Group by equipment_name
```

It is returning only the counts with values higher than 0 , but I need to know the records that are not returning anything.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

thanks,

Marco

Comment: Can more than one record have the same eqp value on ne_list? Does ne_list hold all equipment names that you want to see, or is there another table that lists equipment?

Comment: no, those are unique ids

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `LEFT JOIN`,

```
SELECT  a.eqp, COUNT(b.equipment_name) totalCount
FROM    ne_db.ne_list a
        LEFT JOIN alarms.new_alarms b
            ON a.eqp = b.equipment_name
GROUP   BY a.eqp
```

Answer (score 2):

If the table `ne_list` has no duplicates, then you can do a `left join`.  That assumption may not be true, so the safest way to convert this is by removing duplicates in a subquery:

```
select count(1), ne.equipment_name 
from   alarms.new_alarms ne left outer join
       (select distinct eqp
        from ne_db.ne_list
       ) eqp
       on ne.equipment_name = eqp.eqp
Group by ne.equipment_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `left join`:

```
select  ne.equipment_name 
,       count(na.equipment_name)
from   ne_db.ne_list ne
left join   
       alarms.new_alarms na
on     ne.eqp = na.equipment_name
group by 
       ne.equipment_name
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work too

```
(select equipment_name, count(*) as cnt from alarms.new_alarms 
  where equipment_name in (
     select eqp from ne_db.ne_list
  ) group by equipment_name
)union( 
   select equipment_name, 0 as cnt from alarms.new_alarms 
   where equipment_name not in (
     select eqp from ne_db.ne_list
   ) group by equipment_name
) order by equipment_name
```